# Why begin eating with the bottom challa on Friday evening?

Tags: halacha, minhag

Why do we begin eating with the bottom challa on Friday evening, and only then; not on Shabbat morning and not on holidays (unless they fall on Fri evening)?

Answer (score 0):

It's Al Pi Kabbalah. See Rama 274:1. See Alter Rebbe Shulchan Aruch 274:2 who mentions that on Friday night, in order not to pass on a mitzva, one should place the lower challah closer to oneself, or during the brocha one should place the upper challah on bottom.

Also see Levush 274:1 for a small explanation on the Kabbalistic reason.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why. It recommends a method to ensure this is done.